# Can't Get Contents from text file in Google Drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, text, google-drive-api

I used to Get content from text files on my google drive it works.Then, suddenly stop getting content and it gives me this exception:

> No downloadLink/exportLinks for mimetype found in metadata

what should I do to fix this Problem?
This is my Code:

```
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(r"C:\Users\Microsoft\PycharmProjects\settings.yaml")

if gauth.credentials is None:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    gauth.Authorize()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
fileList = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()

for files in fileList:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (files['title'], files['id']))
  if files['title'] == 'first.txt':

   #Here the Exception Happened After this line
   files.GetContentFile("first.txt")
   files.GetContentString("first.txt")
```

Note:
first.txt-->is a text file in my google drive account contains text.

Comment: Check the mime type of that file.  if its an internal google drive mime type you need to do export not a file.get  also add text to your search root' in parents and trashed=false and mimeType='text/plain'

Comment: - how I can export ?
- how I can add to my search root' in parents and trashed=false and mimeType='text/plain'
-What is 'text/plain'
@DaImTo 
Sorry, But I'm new to pydrive Please Can you explain more

Comment: Did you try just adding it?  "'root' in parents and trashed=false and and mimeType='text/plain'"

Comment: [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) method is use for exporting files of google drive internal mime type. I have a video which explains how download works the beginning is just the explanation, it might help you.  The code example at the end is C# though. [How to download a file using Google Drive api V3](https://youtu.be/VQOrkZrZXB8)